# Issue with caesar cipher and reverse text program

Tags: c, string, pointers

I'm trying to make a function that gets a string and a number and if the number is bigger the '0' so it will make the caesar cipher with the string and the number that the user entered. for example -> 'stack' and the number is '3' -> 'uvdfn'. if the number is '0' so it will reverse the string. for example - 'stack' -> 'kcats'

I don't know what is the issue with the code, i don't see anything wrong.

```html
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void decryptText(char* encText, int n);

#define STR_SIZE 50
int main(void)
{
 char str[STR_SIZE];
 int num = 0;

 printf("Please enter the string : ");
 fgets(str, STR_SIZE, stdin);

 printf("Please enter a number : ");
 scanf("%d", &num);

 decryptText(str, num);

    system("PAUSE");
 return 0;
}


void decryptText(char* encText, int n)
{
 int i = 0;
 int j = 0;
 char temp = 0;

 int strLen = strlen(encText);

 if (n > 0)
 {
  for (i = 0; i < strLen; i++)
  {
   if (*(encText + i) == ' ') { }
   else
   {
    if (*(encText + i) >= 'x')
    {
     *(encText + i) = (*(encText + i)) - 26;
    }
    *(encText + i) = (*(encText + i)) + n;
   }
  }

  printf("The array after the program deciphered it : \n");
  printf("%s", encText);
 }

 else if (n == 0)
 {
  for (i = 0; i < strLen; i++)
  {
   for (j = 0; j >= 0; j--)
   {
    temp = *(encText + i);
    *(encText + i) = *(encText + j);
    *(encText + i) = temp;
   }
  }

  printf("The array after the program cracked it : \n");
  printf("%s", encText);
 }
}
```

Comment: "I don't know what is the issue with the code" - well, we don't know either. Why don't you take a couple of minutes to explain exactly what the problem is? (i.e., what input have you tested it with, what incorrect output did you get, what were your observations when you debugged your code step-by-step, etc).

Comment: `for (j = 0; j >= 0; j--)` will not do anything.

Comment: Hey Barak, sorry...
The problem is that in the case of the caesar cipher, nothing is happening, it doesn't print the result of it.
In the case of the reverse text, it prints the same string that the user entered.
@barakmanos

Comment: And what were your observations when you debugged your code step-by-step?

Comment: At the debugging the caesar cipher worked good i guess i didn't print it well, and in the reversing text i guess i just didn't do it good.

Comment: THe black cat has ran out the door. Mystic meg phone is off the hook. Please advise to the neXT course of action

Comment: LOL, a poster on the C tag actually doing any debugging before posting.  That would be a first :((

Answer (score 0):

```
if (*(encText + i) >= 'x')
    {
        *(encText + i) = (*(encText + i)) - 26;
    }
```

Should be

```
if (*(encText + i) + n > 'z')
{
    *(encText + i) = (*(encText + i)) - 26;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but from some reason if i enter 'wxyz' as a string and '4' as a number it prints '{|}~'

Answer (score 0):

The error in your encoding part is the following snippet:

```
if (*(encText + i) >= 'x')
{
    *(encText + i) = (*(encText + i)) - 26;
}
*(encText + i) = (*(encText + i)) + n;
```

First of all you have to determine if you get lower- or uppercase input. For beginning we assume lowercase input only.
In this snippet you firstly have to subtract an 'a' from the actual character, secondly add the chosen rotation number to the calculated value, thirdly calculate the modul of that and fourthly add an 'a' to the value.

```
char temp;
temp = *(encText + i);
temp -= 'a';
temp += n;
temp %= 26;
temp += 'a';
*(encText + i) = temp;
```

or in short:

```
*(encText + i) = (*(encText + i) - 'a' + n) % 26 + 'a';
```

BTW: Your cracking operation doesnt look very effective...